# CodeIgniter htaccess subfolder problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, subdirectory

I want a second website in my domain inside the folder test

www.mydomian.com/test

Apache server running on linux.

But when I load it in my navigator styles, images, helpers can't be found.

My htaccess is like this:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /test

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Thank you in advance

I have tried what you said, placing the htaccess file you gave me in the test folder and the other one in the root directory,  it didn't work.

Other options?

Comment: So your running a CodeIgniter webiste on your www.domain.com and you want a second inside www.domain.com/test?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a .htaccess file into your test folder instead.

I use this .htaccess content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

In the folder *test* I would place another .htaccess, with almost the same content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/index.php?/$1 [L]
```