# codeigniter wont redirect a url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I did what it is said in the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I put the above, so that I will be able to do this:

```
http://localhost/Speakom2/Home/index
```

Instead of:

```
http://localhost/Speakom2/index.php/Home/index
```

But it doesnt work... I get 404 error..how to fix this so it works?!?

Controller:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

public function Index() 
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
```

}

htaccess:

```
  RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter htaccess subfolder problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527491/codeigniter-htaccess-subfolder-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are running on the local host your web root is `/localhost/mysite/` but in the real host your root is `/mysite` :
so in localhost use  :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

note that index.php without `/`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your `.htaccess` file is in `Speakom2` folder (Codeigniter root directory). And change to this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

//this is .htaccess file just replace it

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase //

```
#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```