# codeigniter remove index.php XAMP for Linux

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I am also having the same problem and I have tried almost every code available online for .htaccess

My Xamp is running on Linux, FYI - The application is on intranet not on internet, may be that cause some problem.

I have checked that mod_rewrite is enabled. it is showing under loaded modules when I run php.info() function.

In my config file

```
$config['base_url'] = ''; 
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol' = 'AUTO';
```

my working url is arteri is a subdirectory in root http://whintranet.wh.tvh.ca/arteri/index.php/artery/home but when I removes index.php from it

The requested URL /arteri/artery/home was not found on this server. Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at whintranet.wh.tvh.ca Port 80

my.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /arteri/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

any help greately appreciated

Comment: There's a missing closing bracket in the snippet from your config file `['uri_protocol']` ... also, you may need to add `QSA` to your last `RewriteRule`: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Set your base url to the absolute path including protocol [as stated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792268/how-to-set-proper-codeigniter-base-url). *Don't forget the trailing slash*

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://whintranet.wh.tvh.ca/arteri/'; 
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol' = 'AUTO';
```

Set your [htaccess according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527491/codeigniter-htaccess-subfolder-problem)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /arteri/index.php?/$1 [L]
```